# rotate camera use lookat function with pan gesture

Tags: ios, swift, opengl-es, metal

I try use lookat function rotate camera with pan gesture. I use swift and Metal(in this case Metal work the same with OpenGLES). Here is my code

The lookat function:

```
 let kEye = V3f(0.0, 0.0, -2.0)
 var ktarget = V3f(0.0, 0.0, 0.0)
 let kUp = V3f(0.0, 1.0, 0.0)    
 var viewMatrix = lookAt(kEye, center: ktarget, up: kUp)
```

The pan gesture:

```
func pan(panGesture: UIPanGestureRecognizer){

        if panGesture.state == UIGestureRecognizerState.Changed{
            let pointInView = panGesture.locationInView(self.view)
            let xDelta = (lastPanLocation.x - pointInView.x)/self.view.bounds.width * panSensivity
            let yDelta = (lastPanLocation.y - pointInView.y)/self.view.bounds.height * panSensivity
            lastPanLocation = pointInView

            var viewDirection = rotationM3f(kUp, angle: Float(-xDelta)) * viewDirection
            var toRotateAround = Cross(viewDirection, b: kUp)
            viewDirection = rotationM3f(toRotateAround, angle: Float(-yDelta)) * viewDirection
            ktarget = kEye + viewDirection

        } else if panGesture.state == UIGestureRecognizerState.Began {
            lastPanLocation = panGesture.locationInView(self.view)
        }
    }
```

At the beginning, it works fine, pan the camera after a while, the viewDirection and toRotateAround vector will become -0.0,-0.0,0.0, when finger move vertically but the camera does not look up and down, Anyone knows what is wrong in the code? Thanks~~~

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You only modify the view direction (`ktarget` in the end) but forget about `kUP`. Once these 2 vectors become parallel the cross product is zero and everything breaks.

The solution you are looking for is recomputing the `kUp` vector by using a cross product of `viewDirection` and `toRotateAround`.

When using rotations like this you need to think of your data as base vectors and a position (`location=kEye`, `forward=ktarget-keye`, `up=kUp`, `right=cross(forward, up)`). The base vectors are always perpendicular to each other (I suggest them to be normalized as well) and when you rotate you always rotate one of these vectors around another base vectors and after the rotation you need to recompute the 3rd vector by using a cross product.

So to rotate left or right you would rotate the `forward` around `up` and then use a cross product between `forward` and `up` to get the `right` vector. (The right vector here is optional since you do not use it)

To rotate up or down you rotate `forward` vector around `right` vector and use a cross product between the `forward` and `right` to get the new `top` vector.

Then for tilting left or right you rotate `up` around `forward` and get the `right` vector with cross product of the 2 used vectors.

If you see the logic you will find out there are always 2 ways of rotating along one axis. For instance to rotate left or right you might as well rotate the `right` vector around `up` and find the new forward vector by using a cross product of `right` and `up`.

There is a trick though. The procedure described here works great for a free movement such as a flight simulation where you can "tilt". It is not appropriate for a movement such as for a first person shooter where up is always in the center of the screen horizontally (I hope you see the difference). To create this FPS way you actually do need to keep `up` as `(0,1,0)` but then forward must never be `(0,1,0)` but it can be `(0.001, 0.09, 0)` which is pretty close to looking directly upwards. So as long as you limit the upwards angle to some value you should be fine. There are other ways as well...

Comment: Thanks, I would try, but To rotate up or down, what do you mean get the new top vector. The top vector is the vector up or kup or forward? @Matic Oblak

Comment: And how and where should I modify the ktarget vector? @Matic Oblak

Comment: var location = kEye
        var forward = ktarget + -kEye
        var up = kUp
        var right = Cross(forward, b: up)
            forward = rotationM3f(up, angle: Float(xDelta)) * forward
            right = Cross(forward, b: up)

            forward = rotationM3f(right, angle: Float(yDelta)) * forward
            up = Cross(forward, b: right)

            up = rotationM3f(forward, angle: Float(xDelta)) * up
            right = Cross(up, b: forward)
            ktarget = kEye + forward is this okay? @Matic Oblak

Comment: I have written what is up, forward, right and position in the 3rd paragraph. Ktarget can be computed from those. Sorry about the"top" I meant "up". The kTarget would best be computed in the lookAt call as position+forward.. simply replace it with forward as you really never need the "kTarget".

Comment: sorry, for one more foolish question,  what is the postion? is location = kEye, right? @ Matic Oblak

Comment: Yes. These values can be represented by a 4x4 matrix where the left 4x3 matrix would consist of: right, up, forward, position which are the base vectors plus position. Ergo for identity right(1,0,0), up(0,1,0), forward(0,0,1), position(0,0,0). This also means you may use a single matrix to define all of these values and the operations on the matrix will already give you the full result you are looking for. For instance if this matrix would be multiplied by translation matrix (0,0,1) the effect would be moving forward by 1 unit no matter which way you are facing.

Comment: Thanks, But still not work well, why we need to tilting left or right? do we also need to tilting up and down? I right this code for tilting left and right: up = rotationM3f(forward, angle: Float(xDelta)) * up
            right = Cross(up, b: forward), @Matic Oblak

Comment: The same goes for rotations.. Multiplying it with rotation matrix around (0,0,1) will always result in turning left or right from the first person perspective, so no "up" vector is needed. All you need to do is construct the forward, right, up and position vectors from the matrix the same way I mentioned above.

Comment: You might not need them, it is just a feature you might need or not

Comment: A more specific explanation on what you are trying to achieve would lead to a better answer. But due to all the comments I suggest you ask another question with all details in it.

Comment: Thanks, I did ask another one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36360738/rotate-camera-up-and-down-left-and-right-with-pan-gesture, @Matic Oblak