# rotate camera up and down, left and right with pan gesture

Tags: ios, swift, opengl-es, metal

I want to rotate camera up or down and left or right to look around an object, (360 degrees view) with pan gesture using opengl lookat function, I use swift and Metal(in this case Metal = opengl es). here is the code:

the lookat function(this function is in another ViewController which is inheritance from the main ViewController which is with the viewDidLoad and pan gesture function):

```
let viewMatrix = lookAt(location, center: ktarget, up: up)
```

the viewDidLoad and var:

```
 var ktarget = V3f()
 var up = V3f()
 let location =V3f()

override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()        
        location = V3f(0.0, 0.0, -2.0)
        ktarget = V3f(0.0, 0.0, 0.0)
        up = V3f(0.0, 1.0, 0.0)
}
```

the pan gesture:

```
    func pan(panGesture: UIPanGestureRecognizer){
       up = V3f(0.0, 1.0, 0.0).Normalized()
       forward = (ktarget + -location).Normalized()
       right = Cross(forward, b: up).Normalized()

            if panGesture.state == UIGestureRecognizerState.Changed{  
               let pointInView = panGesture.locationInView(self.view)
               let xDelta = (lastPanLocation.x - pointInView.x)/self.view.bounds.width * panSensivity
               let yDelta = (lastPanLocation.y - pointInView.y)/self.view.bounds.height * panSensivity
            //        To rotate left or right, rotate the forward around up and then use a cross product between forward and up to get the right vector.
               forward = rotationM3f(up, angle: Float(xDelta)) * forward.Normalized()
               right = Cross(forward, b: up).Normalized()
            //        To rotate up or down, rotate forward vector around right vector and use a cross product between the right and forward to get the new up vector.
               forward = rotationM3f(right, angle: Float(yDelta)) * forward.Normalized()
               up = V3f(0.0, 1.0, 0.0).Normalized()
               ktarget = location + forward
               lastPanLocation = pointInView
            } else if panGesture.state == UIGestureRecognizerState.Began {
               ktarget = location + forward
               lastPanLocation = panGesture.locationInView(self.view)
            }
        }
```

But pan the camera, I set up the up vector always =(0,1,0), to make people only can see 180 degree vertically. If user still pan When Camera look up or down(max value)the screen will flip, the real value x and z of target is changed little by little(very small numebr, such as 0.0000somenumber) every frames, so the draw function will draw the object very little difference every frames. Anyone knows how can fix the flip? Thanks~~~

Comment: This is not the issue but: Never normalize the location, only the base vectors. When you call "normalized" method it is most likely a = a.normalized() or there is no visible result.

Comment: What exactly is your result at this point? I would expect flickering as I believe it should be up=cross(right, forward), and not cross(forward, right) ? Anyway if this is correct then the only way I see the result (0,0,0) was possible is due to not having the base vectors normalized.

Comment: emm...when I pan, the object will disappear... @Matic Oblak

Comment: Put a breakpoint and see which vector changes drastically and to what

Comment: I am sorry but I usually set up these methods by myself so I know exactly what they do and how

Comment: the forword, right and up vector not calculate right, I though maybe the xDelta, yDelta or the math about rotation is wrong... print pangesture change state, The first 3 times are okay, from the fourth time, value got too big and the fith time, got nan value or 0.0 from all these 3 vector @Matic Oblak

Comment: my rotation return a 3X3 matrix, @ Matic Oblak

Comment: My bad, forget ai said anythig

Comment: Those values you posted now are way too large. Maybe an overflow accrued? Do normalize those vectors as up = Cross(a, b).normalized()

Comment: But not the location obviously

Comment: normalized the up vector fixed the value too large and the object disappear, but it not lookat the right position... @Matic Oblak

Comment: Hi, I change a bit, do you see something wrong? @Matic Oblak